# GameCenter iOS leaderboard identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, game-center

this is my code to get the default leaderboard in game center but return a nil value.

and i have this info in the iTunes connect  what can i do? thanks

**This image is from iTunes Connect**

[image: This image is from iTunes Connect]

**This is from Xcode**
[image: This is from Xcode]

**This is from device**
[image: This is from device]

and the code to obtain the default leaderboard

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else{
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;

                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString * _Nullable leaderboardIdentifier, NSError * _Nullable error) {


                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                    }else{

                        _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier; // **This contains nil value**

                    }

                }];
            }else{

                _gameCenterEnabled=NO;
            }
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You code looks fine. Did you try signing out and back into Game Center on your device? I have this happening to me a few times in sandbox mode as well and a signing out and back in usually fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this strange problem creating a new leaderboard and create a new version of my application for example 1.1 and this works for me.

Thanks for your answer **crashoverride777**